# How does es7 object spread notational create a shallow copy to replace original object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to learn Redux as well as es7 from [here](https://github.com/happypoulp/redux-tutorial/blob/master/04_get-state.js) and have trouble understanding the author's point below about the following code:

> Note also that this ES7 Object Spread notation suits our example
>   because it's doing a shallow        copy of { message: action.value
>   } over our state (meaning that first level properties of state
>   are completely overwritten - as opposed to gracefully merged - by
>   first level property of     { message: action.value }).

```
var reducer_3 = function (state = {}, action) {
    console.log('reducer_3 was called with state', state, 'and action', action)

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SAY_SOMETHING':
            return {
                ...state,
                message: action.value
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

How is the first level properties of state overwritten by {message: action.value} when the author's use of Object Spread notation simply **adds** the message: action.value key/value pair to the original state? The first level of properties of state are still there because of the Object Spread notation right? Thus, if the original state was `{a:"foo", b:"bar"}` the new state after dispatching an action of `SAY_SOMETHING` would be `{a:"foo", b:"bar", message: 'SAY_SOMETHING}`, correct? Nothing was replaced.

Comment: `{...a, b:1} == Object.assign({}, a, b:1}`

Comment: Object spread is a **proposal**. It is not part of ES7.

Comment: It *is* replaced if the property was already present in `state`.

Answer (score 1):

It will only override IFF it is replacing an existing property. So, your example is exactly correct. The author mentioned that it would do a shallow merge, which would override existing keys, but gave an example that simply added a property as you said. Maybe send a PR to clarify :)

When using the spread operator to create a new object, it behaves exactly like [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) in Underscore/Lo-dash with an empty object literal as the first argument. So, these are all equivalent...

```
Object.assign({}, a, b)
_.extend({}, a, b)
{ ...a, ...b }
```

As you can see in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20one%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%22foo%22%2C%20b%3A%22bar%22%20%7D%0Aconst%20two%20%3D%20%7B%20...one%2C%20message%3A%20'SAY_SOMETHING'%20%7D), Babel simply converts this syntax to  `Object.assign`, if its available, or a polyfill of `Object.assign`